# 2D game design - y variable not resolved?

Tags: java, 2d, block

I have my code as the following.

```
package net.ferrell.wrathoftuemdaym;

import java.awt.*;

public class Level {
    public Block[][] block = new Block[50][50];

    public Level() {
        for(int x = 0; x < block.length; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < block[0].length; y++);
                block[x][y] = new Block(new Rectangle(x * Tile.tileSize, y * Tile.tileSize, Tile.tileSize, Tile.tileSize), Tile.air);
        }

    }

    public void generateLevel() {
        for(int x = 0; x < block.length; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < block[0].length; y++);
                if(x == 0 || y == 0 || x == block.length-1 || y == block[0].length-1) {
                    block[x][y].id = Tile.earth;
                }
        }

    }

    public void tick() {


    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        for(int x = 0; x < block.length; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < block[0].length; y++);
                block[x][y].render(g);
        }


    }
}
```

In a line that says " block[x][y] ", y cannot be resolved to a variable. I do not know the fix for this and it is only in this class that the problem exists. Please help me. I do not understand because the x CAN be resolved...

Comment: 1) Don't SHOUT at us. 2) *'In a line that says " block[x][y] "'*  I see 3 such lines.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & copy/paste the compilation output into the question (also using code formatting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is your culprit

```
for(int y = 0; y < block[0].length; y++);
```

it should be

```
for(int y = 0; y < block[0].length; y++)
```

Personally I always put braces in code blocks even if it is just one line.

Comment: @user2002536: Please remember to accept answers that solve your question.